# Show MS Dynamics 2016 (On Premise) Contacts List within SharePoint (On Premise)

Tags: sharepoint, dynamics-crm

We use SharePoint for our Customer Projects. We also use MS CRM 2016. So it would be helpful to store all contacts and accounts info within MS CRM but also show this on the SharePoint project pages. Has anyone achieved this? Is there any plugin for SharePoint we should use for this?

Answer (score 0):

You have limited options. With the latest versions & online environments, you can build a low-code Canvas PowerApp out of Dynamics 365/CDS connector & embed in SharePoint.

You have to use code solution using CRM REST web api query in Ajax call from a web part to list the Accounts/Contacts.

Some other options listed in [this blogpost](https://crmbook.powerobjects.com/system-administration/sharepoint-document-management/accessing-crm-from-sharepoint/) including BCS connector can be tried.